# Trying to reformat a list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, data-analysis

I have a column called genres in my dataframe where each row consists of a list of dictionaries objects. For example, here is the first row:

```
[{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 14, "name": "Fantasy"}, {"id": 878, "name": "Science Fiction"}]
```

What I would like to do is reformat this so that each row only contains the information found in the "name" key, preferably dumped into a list.

So for example, the output for the first row would resemble the following:

```
["Action", "Adventure", "Fantasy", "Science Fiction"]
```

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Does your example show one column in the first row or does it represent multiple columns of the first row?

Comment: I have multiple columns - genres just being one of them. Unfortunately when I attempt the solutions below I get the following: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Answer (score 3):

Use list-comprehension that takes out each dictionary out of list and extract `'name'`:

```
[x['name'] for x in lst]
```

In **code**:

```
lst = [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 14, "name": "Fantasy"}, {"id": 878, "name": "Science Fiction"}]

print([x['name'] for x in lst])
# ['Action', 'Adventure', 'Fantasy', 'Science Fiction']
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. However I'm getting the following: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Can you do `print(type(lst[0]))`?

Comment: When I try that method I still get the following: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: What is the output of `print(type(lst[0]))` ?

Comment: <class 'str'> is the output

Comment: So you are not having list of dictionaries as you told in the question. That's why the error. Does the list look exactly similar as you specified in the question? Do you miss some quotes?

Comment: The list looks exactly similar.

Comment: What is the output of `print(lst)` ?

Comment: 0       [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "nam...
1       [{"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 14, "...
2       [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "nam...
3       [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 80, "nam...
4       [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "nam...
5       [{"id": 14, "name": "Fantasy"}, {"id": 28, "na...
6       [{"id": 16, "name": "Animation"}, {"id": 10751...
7       [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "nam...
8       [{"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 14, "...
9       [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "nam...

Comment: output for print(genres[0]) is [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 14, "name": "Fantasy"}, {"id": 878, "name": "Science Fiction"}]

Answer (score 3):

```
data = [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 14, "name": "Fantasy"}, {"id": 878, "name": "Science Fiction"}]

out = [x['name'] for x in data]

print(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) using `'name'` as the key

```
import operator

lst = [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, 
       {"id": 14, "name": "Fantasy"}, {"id": 878, "name": "Science Fiction"}]

answer = list(map(operator.itemgetter('name'), lst))

# ["Action", "Adventure", "Fantasy", "Science Fiction"]
```